# Prove that the series $a_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha}{2}-\frac{a_n^2}{2}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $a_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha}{2}-\frac{a_n^2}{2}$ with $a_1=\frac{\alpha}{2}$, $0\leq\alpha\leq1$

Prove that $a_n$ converges.

I guess that this can be solved by proving that $a_n$ is bounded and monotonic. I've tried to show that it is descending by looking at $a_{n+1}-a_n$ but with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll try to prove inductively that the sequence is monotone.

$$a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{a_{n-1}^2 - a_n^2}{2}$$

Suppose $a_1 \leq a_2$. Then inductively $a_{n-1} \leq a_n$, so $a_{n-1}^2 \leq a_n^2$ and hence $a_{n+1} - a_n < 0$; so $a_n \geq a_{n+1}$.

Oh no! We've actually proved inductively that the sequence is alternating between being increasing and decreasing! (You can flesh out the above idea into an actual proof, rather than a failed proof of something else.)

OK, but what we do have is that inductively $$|a_{n+1}| = |\frac{\alpha}{2} - \frac{a_n^2}{2}| \leq \frac{\alpha}{2} + \frac{1}{2} a_n^2 \leq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1$$
where the last inequality is by inductive hypothesis.

Therefore the sequence is bounded by $[-1, 1]$.
In fact, we can tighten this to being bounded by $[-\alpha, \alpha]$ by noting that $$\frac{\alpha}{2} + \frac{1}{2} a_n^2 \leq \frac{\alpha}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \alpha^2 \leq \frac{1}{2} \alpha + \frac{1}{2} \alpha = \alpha$$

Notice that $f(x) = \frac{\alpha}{2} - \frac{x^2}{2}$ is a contraction mapping on $[-r,r]$ whenever $r < 1$: $$d(f(x), f(y)) = \frac{1}{2} d(x^2, y^2) = \frac{1}{2} |x+y| |x-y| \leq r |x-y| = r \times d(x, y)$$
and $[-r, r]$ is a complete nonempty metric space (if $r > 0$), so by the contraction mapping theorem, iterating $f$ from any starting point will produce a convergent sequence.

Therefore $f$ is a contraction on $[-\alpha, \alpha]$, which is enough as long as $\alpha$ is not $0$ or $1$.

If $\alpha = 0$, the sequence is constant $0$. I'm still working on the case $\alpha = 1$. (EDIT: which is taken care of nicely by Hua in another answer, who points out that we can prove $|a_n| \leq \frac{\alpha}{2}$ in all cases, not just $|a_n| \leq \alpha$.)

Answer (score 0):

We can see $a_n\leq \frac{\alpha}{2}\ \forall n\in\mathbb N$ and we can prove $a_n\geq 0\ \forall n\in\mathbb N$:

Assume $n$ is minimal with $a_n<0$, then $a_{n-1}^2>\alpha$ and since $a_{n-1}\geq 0$, we get a contradiction with $a_{n-1}\leq \frac{\alpha}{2}$.

Now you can proceed as described in the other answer.